# GCM : Message delivered only while debugging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am stuck with an issue.

I am developing an application which is using the GCM push notification functionality. While debugging all the messages are getting delivered(with/without some amount of varying delays) to the device. But when I unplug the device from the PC or disable debugging mode GCM messages are not getting delivered (I actually waited for more than 3 hours with active internet connection and google account).

And again when I plugin the device back to PC and enable USB debugging it starts receiving GCM messages.

Guys I am really scratching my head hard to get pass this weird issue. Can you please give me some direction or correct me if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting airplane mode on, then off again. Not an explanation or a long term fix I know, but it often seems to jog GCM back into life

Comment: @NickT I tried doing so...but no success....do have to do something else to make it work on real device.. ???

Comment: I can't suggest anything else, sorry

Comment: Have you tried to use both WiFi connection and mobile data connection when testing GCM without debugging?

Comment: yes...both of them were on....but it worked while debugging....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey after wasting my whole day on this question I came across a line which I wrote for debugging the IntentService

`android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

this was the line responsible for all the above weird behavior. It might be obvious to remove or not to use this line (I would like to apologies if it is the case for wasting your precious time). But it might help someone like me in the future (at least I  can say so... :P).

Anyways thank a lot for your timely responses.

Comment: Where did you put this line? I don't think I have this line in my code and I have the same problem.

Comment: @RenanBandeira Actually this line was the issue. This line was in the Service which I wrote for GCM request and response. If you use this code for debugging the GCM, do remove it without fail, when you are done with the debugging. Otherwise issue as mentioned above will occur.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that the problem was the limit of keys used in the gcm message